# How to expand the clickable area of v-switch in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The default `v-switch` can be clicked on the surface of a switch and a label only. I want to append the padding area in `v-switch`. My switch locates inside the `v-app-bar`.

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar app color="blue">
    <v-switch id="switch-to-run" class="py-5 " inset
      color="purple" label="Execute Program" hide-details="auto"/>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

However, there is no extra area. Can I expand the padding of `v-switch`?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by padding area, but you can update the v-model of a `v-switch` on clicking other elements.

Comment: For example, do I need to add another clickable div element which contains `v-switch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `label` slot and add any element you want like this example :

```
 <v-switch v-model="switchMe">
        <template v-slot:label>
          <span class="pr-2">     
            Click the button:
          </span>
          <v-btn color="primary" >switch</v-btn>
        </template>
 </v-switch>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/wvJjxPW)**